# Get one value from array output?

Tags: php, arrays

Im trying to work out how to get the value from one setting in an array.

When i do this

```
<?php 
$data = array($settings);
echo "<pre>";
echo print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

I get this ( but i dont want to just spit the array out like below )

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [layout] => pizza:simple
            [style] => pizza:red
        )

)
1
```

I tried this but no luck ( What i need is just the value of **layout** or **style** )

```
<?php
$data = array($settings);
$layout = $data->layout;
?>
```

So basically i can now use the $layout value for things i want to do on the page.

How do i do this please?

Thanks in advance :)
jonny

Comment: Why do you array-ify `$settings` anyway? It's already an array. Access like so, `$settings['layout']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$data[0]['layout']` or `$data[0]['style']`

This is an associative array so its basically an array inside of an array. So if you had another value 1 it could have a different layout and pizza and it would be accessed by $data[1]['layout'] etc

Comment: Ok thats cool! thank you, it worked. Can you explain why as well. Im doing everything backwards. Learning without manuals or school. I just pick it up as i go along.

Comment: This is an associative array so its basically an array inside of an array.  So if you had another value 1 it could have a different layout and pizza and it would be accessed by $data[1]['layout'] etc

Comment: Please edit your answer and move your comments up into there to provide more details for posterity.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if you intend to use

`$data->layout`

You will have to define class and layout as its property

```
class Settings {
    public $layout;
    public $style;

    public function __construct($data = null) {
         $this->layout = $data['layout'];
         $this->style = $data['style'];
    }
}

// you can now use it

$data = new Settings($settings);
echo $data->layout; // this will work
```